# Conversion of an implicit to an explicit funtion

Tags: functions, lambert-w

${1  \over a}({1 \over x} - {1 \over x_0}) - b \ln({x \over x_0}) = t$; where $a, x_0$ and $b$ are constants. Find an explicit function $t \mapsto x(t)$.

I was suggested the use of Lambert W function to get an explicit function x(t). Anyone familiar with it?

Comment: Since I see $x$ and $\ln(x)$ mixed, most likely $x(t)$ is transcendental.

Comment: @Jared Can I please get a step-by step solution?

Comment: Transcendental means _there is no_ "step-by-step" solution.

Comment: I was suggested the use of Lambert W function to get an explicit function x(t). Anyone familiar with it?

Comment: You might want to mention that in your question.  The Lambert W function is transcendental--it's not magic as if you can automatically ("easily") evaluate a function just because you call it a function.

Comment: @Jared So you are saying finding an explicit function x(t) is not possible?

Comment: @Jared No hate man, I just need to know if its possible or not.

Comment: "possible" is a relative term.  Since the OP mentioned Lambert, I suspect there _is_ a way to express this in terms of Lambert W functions (but this is beyond my knowledge).  I can create any weird equation you can think of and give a function which solves it (assuming it can be solved).  The question here, I suspect, is whether or not this function can be expressed as a solution of a more general equation (the Lambert W function).

Comment: A lot of people are familiar with the Lambert W function, and many of those people have written stuff about it, and posted that stuff to the web. Have you tried typing "Lambert W" into your favorite websearch engine to see what comes up? After you've done that, if you need help in understanding what you have found --- that's the time to come back here, to ask a focussed question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As expected, the inverse function involves the Lambert W function :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For any equation of the form $$a + b x + c \log(d + e x)=0$$ $x$ can be expressed in terms of Lambert function and the result is (I assume that all coefficients are non zero $$x=\frac{c W(z)}{b}-\frac{d}{e}$$ in which $$z=\frac{b e^{\frac{b d-a e}{c e}}}{c e}$$ In your case, start replacing $x=\frac{1}{y}$ which makes your expression very close to the one I wrote and you will obtain what JJacquelin answered.